# Installing A Package With Cython Files

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I am trying to install a package where some of the files are built with Cython. My `setup.py` looks like:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py as _build_py


from Cython.Build import cythonize

def readme():
      with open('README.md') as f:
            return f.read()

with open("requirements.txt", "r") as fh:
   requirements = fh.readlines()


def get_ext_paths(root_dir):
    """get filepaths for compilation"""
    paths = []

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
        if root.startswith("mypkg/dir1") or \
                root.startswith("mypkg/dir2") or \
                root.startswith("mypkg/dir3"):
            continue

        for filename in files:
            if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] != '.py':
                continue

            file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            paths.append(file_path)

    return paths

# noinspection PyPep8Naming
class build_py(_build_py):

    def find_package_modules(self, package, package_dir):
        ext_suffix = sysconfig.get_config_var('EXT_SUFFIX')
        modules = super().find_package_modules(package, package_dir)
        filtered_modules = []
        for (pkg, mod, filepath) in modules:
            if os.path.exists(filepath.replace('.py', ext_suffix)):
                continue
            filtered_modules.append((pkg, mod, filepath, ))
        return filtered_modules

setup(name='my-pkg',
      version='0.1',
      description='My description',
      long_description=readme(),
      classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.0',
        'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering',
      ],
      keywords='my-keyword',
      url='https://github.com/MyProject/mypkg',
      author='First Last',
      author_email='firstlast@example.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['mypkg',
                'mypkg.dir0',
                'mypkg.dir1',
                'mypkg.dir2',
                'mypkg.dir3',
                'mypkg.dir3.dir4'],
      ext_modules=cythonize(get_ext_paths('mypkg'), compiler_directives={'language_level': 3}),
      install_requires=[req for req in requirements if req[:2] != "# "],
      include_package_data=True,
      zip_safe=False)
```

I am able to install the Python version with

```
pip install .
```

However, no matter what I run to build the `setup.py`, I cannot make the Cython version visible outside the package.

For example, inside the package folders, when I run:

```
from mypkg import MyClass
print(MyClass.mymethod)
```

I get:

```
<cyfunction MyClass.mymethod at 0x7ff2f4ef65f0>
```

But as soon as I move out of the root directory, I get

```
<function MyClass.mymethod at 0x7f62b77c78b0>
```

I have tried

```
pip install .
```

```
python setup.py install
```

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
pip install .
```

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
pip install dist/my_pkg-0.1-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
```

It would be great to have some insight into the sequence of commands necessary to install the Cython version.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "I cannot make the Cython version visible outside the package"? Is `MyClass.mymethod` supposed to be a method that returns the Cython verion? If so, you're forgetting to call it: try `print(MyClass.mymethod())`

Comment: I just meant that as a way to check if the Python version or the Cython version was running. Inside the root directory, printing the function object directly prints the type as a cyfunction, but outside, the type is just a function. Either way, the code runs, I think it is just using the slow version.